# input tag of html to display only integer value even if it has decimal places

Tags: html, visualforce

I have input tag of html as follow

```
<input type="number" value="1.000" />
```

and actually the value is coming dynamically.
Now what i want is whenever it shows above code value it should show only 1 
it should not show the decimal places 
and this is in visualforce page.

Comment: there no such html tag or attribute, you need to write custom javascript code to achive this.

Comment: Ok then can you post that javascript?